# Storing data from json file using python - adding tuple of data to dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have a json file with lots of claims like this and I'm trying to loop through the file and for each unique year in reviewDate, store every unique claimant with a counter for how often it appears

```
    {
      "text": "“This president, though, for immigrants, there is nothing he will not do to separate a family, cage a child, or erase their existence by weaponizing the census.\"",
      "claimant": "Eric Swalwell",
      "claimDate": "2019-06-27T00:00:00Z",
      "claimReview": [
        {
          "publisher": {
            "name": "PolitiFact",
            "site": "politifact.com"
          },
          "url": "https://www.politifact.com/article/2019/jun/28/fact-checking-2nd-night-democratic-debate-miami/",
          "title": "Fact-checking the 2nd night of the Democratic debate in Miami",
          "reviewDate": "2019-06-28T16:49:26Z",
          "textualRating": "Frequent attack needs context",
          "languageCode": "en"
        }
      ]
    },
```

I have this script right now, but it just adds a new entry for every single entry instead of find the claimant in the dictionary and incrementing its counter

```
def split_by_year(data):
    year_dict = {}
    claimant_dict = {}
    counter = 0
    # for every claim in the file
    for claim in data['claims']:
        # placeholder for year & claimant
        year = ''
        claimant = ''
        if 'claimant' in claim:
            claimant = claim['claimant']
            # the reviewDate is in the review so we go into it
            for review in claim['claimReview']:
                # if the review date exists
                if 'reviewDate' in review.keys():
                    # get the year
                    year = review['reviewDate'][0:4]

                    if year in year_dict:
                        # loop through to find the claimant
                        if claimant in year_dict[year]:
                            counter += 1
                            year_dict[year][1] += 1
                        else:
                            # claimant doesnt exist
                            year_dict[year].append([claimant, 1])
                    else:
                        # year not in year_dict. Add w/ counter
                        year_dict[year] = [claimant, 1]
```

This is the current output

```
 '2019': ['Eric Swalwell',
          3,
          ['Ted Budd', 1],
          ['Donald Trump', 1],
          ['Henry Cuellar', 1],
          ['Mike Pence', 1],
          ['Mike Pence', 1],
          ['Michael Bennet', 1],
          ['Facebook posts', 1],
          ['Donald Trump', 1],
          ['Mark Walker', 1],
```

I'm not sure how to properly add the claimant with a counter under each year. And then also the check if the claimant has already been added, to increment the counter

Answer (score -1):

from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def split_by_year(data):
year_dict = defaultdict(Counter)

```
# for every claim in the file
for claim in data['claims']:
    if 'claimant' in claim:
        claimant = claim['claimant']
    else:
        continue # skip this one, move to next claim

    for review in claim['claimReview']:
        if 'reviewDate' in review.keys():
            year = review['reviewDate'][0:4]
        else:
            continue # skip this one, move to next claimReview

        year_dict[year][claimant] += 1

return year_dict
```

result = split_by_year(data)
print(result['2019']["Eric Swalwell"])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).